# Connotation of "complacence"

Tags: meaning, nouns, connotation

What is the connotation of *complacence*? Is it a negative trait? The dictionary makes it seem like a positive attribute.

Comment: How does a dictionary make it seem positive? [Complacency](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/complacency?q=complacence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complacence is an often unjustified feeling of being pleased with oneself or with one's situation or achievements http://www.merriam-webster.com. It is used to denote egoism , pompousness, self admiration, vanity and the likes making it a negative word. It also refers to lack of interest and concern. It has negative connotation.

Can you quote an example/sentence where it is reflecting positiveness?

Comment: Thanks a lot Matrika. I got the positive vibes from the MW entry - `: calm or secure satisfaction with oneself or one's lot` http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complacence .    I'm thinking the older complaisant may be the culprit

Answer (score 2):

Complacence is negative in the sense that it implies an undeserved or unjustified sense of wellbeing and contentment.

A complacent person feels satisfied (with a situation or with him/herself) to the extent of becoming careless and uninterested in improvement. Similarly, such a person is likely to feel so content that s/he tends to overlook legitimate problems or risks that should, actually, be cause of concern.

Comment: I really agree with `feels satisfied (with a situation or with him/herself) to the extent of becoming careless and uninterested in improvement` - yes, thanks so much.